# Period at the end of print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why but I've just never found a way around this problem.

My teacher wanted to get our class involved with coding and asked me to create a basic calculator in python. So I quickly typed up:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

print (num1, "+", num2, "is equal to", add(num1, num2))
```

Simple stuff, I'll add subtraction and all that.

However, being the grammar nazi I am, I cannot find a way to place a period at the end of that print command.

I've solved it before. My first calculator didn't define functions, it just took the integers, then added them together and assigned them a variable and then printed them. I added periods by using %s and putting the variable at the end of the print command.

Also, while if I try to print the option selected in a tkinter window for example with variable.get() I can't seem to put a period at the end either. The only thing I found only was putting + "." at the end or something along those lines.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
print ("{} + {} is equal to {}.".format(num1, num2, add(num1, num2)))
```

This makes use of the `format()` method documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do:

```
print (str(num1) + "+" + str(num2) + " is equal to " + str(add(num1, num2)) +".")
```

What this does is to convert the numbers to strings and append them into one big string which is then printe.

Much better is to use use a formatter:

```
print ("{0} + {1} is equal to {2}.".format(num1, num2, add(num1, num2))
```

In this example you define a "format" where {n} are replaced by the values passed in the format function. This produces a string that is then printed.

The second way is more elegant and easy to follow in my opinion, so I suggest using that.

Comment: "*What you are currently doing will not work - you are calling the print keyword (which was later replaced by print() function) on a list and that's not what you want.*" - no, he's definitely using the print function. Note the Python 3 tag.